# How to approach building calender within react native app

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, react-native

I'm making an app which people can list their own items for rental. This has been going really well so far and I'm creating successful queries to my firebase firestore

I want users to be able to list their items but then specify when they are available or not. I'm not sure how to approach this.

I would imagine that the data structure at firebase would look like this

```
listedItem: {
    itemName: 'name',
    itemPrice: '£0000'
    itemDescription: 'desc',
    availability: {
        week1: {
            booked: true,
        },
        ...
        week52: {
            booked: false,
        }

    }
}
```

I imagine the structure looking something like this for each listed item but I'm not sure whether this is the best way to approach this

Also I'm not too sure how to go about the UI side of things, Should I build this from scratch using views or can anyone recommend a solid plugin I could use?

Thanks

Comment: what are u using? firebase real time database or firestore?

Comment: I'm using firestore @PeterHaddad